# Dropdown values filter based on another dropdown javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

Here i have three dropdown lists each contains same number of values.So the question is If value 'one' is selected from '#dropdownone'. it should not show value 'one' for the rest of the two dropdown menus. Also if some value is selected from '#dropdowntwo' it should not show the values in the dropdown for the other two elements list. same case for the '#dropdownthree'. But if other values are selected from the list. the previously selected values will show in the rest of the dropdown lists.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/htoniv/4ysmvkgp/)

**HTML**

```
<select id='dropdownone'></select>
<select id='dropdowntwo'></select>
<select id='dropdownthree'></select>
```

**Javascript**

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
$.each(numbers, function( key, value ) {
    if (key == 0) {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdownthree").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");

    } else if (key == 1) {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdownthree").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    } else if (key == 2) {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdownthree").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    } else {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");
       $("#dropdownthree").append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+value+"</option>");    
    }
});
```

**Note:** I need the function works in **onchange** event
for example 
***first time value selection*** if value 'one' is selected from '#dropdownone' it should not show the `one` value in '#dropdowntwo' & '#dropdownthree'. 
***second time value selection*** if value 'two' is selected from '#dropdownone' it should not show the value `two` in '#dropdowntwo' & '#dropdownthree'. but the prevoiusly selected value 'one' should show for the two dropdown elements
***third time value selection*** if again value 'one' is selected from '#dropdownone' it should not show the value in '#dropdowntwo' & '#dropdownthree'.

Comment: Can you explain this line `But if other values are selected from the list. the previously selected values will show in the rest of the dropdown lists.`?

Comment: yeah actually we dynamically select values from dropdown list. so it always get modified. this is what i mentioned.

Comment: @void  if u don't get the question properly please ask me.

Comment: And why are you inserting the `option` using jquery?

Comment: here i used jquery.but i need the answer either in javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this  and repeat the change function for every dropdown you need

```
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
var htmlAppend;
$.each(numbers, function( key, value ) {
    htmlAppend += '<option value="'+key+'">'+value+'</option>';
});
$("#dropdownone, #dropdowntwo, #dropdownthree").html(htmlAppend);
$('#dropdownone').on('change',function(){
    var thisKey = $(this).val();
    $("#dropdowntwo").html(htmlAppend);
    $("#dropdowntwo > option[value='"+ thisKey +"']").remove();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/4ysmvkgp/1/)

Note: if this works with you .. just tell me to explain it better

Comment: in ur demo if i select value 'two' from `'#dropdownone'` the value should not show for the rest of the two dropdown elements.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: @Mohamed-Yousef's answer is way better, go with his instead.**

I am assuming you mean this?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4ysmvkgp/6/)** <- UPDATED TO HIDE

**HTML**

```
<select class="select" id='dropdownone'></select>
<select class="select" id='dropdowntwo'></select>
<select class="select" id='dropdownthree'></select>
```

**JS**

```
console.clear(); // easy debugging
var chosen = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three"};
$(".select").change(function(){
    var index = $(this).index() + 1;
    var value = $(this).val();
    var other = {};
    if(index === 1) { other = ["dropdowntwo", "dropdownthree"]; }
    if(index === 2) { other = ["dropdownone", "dropdownthree"]; }
    if(index === 3) { other = ["dropdownone", "dropdowntwo"]; }

    $.each(other, function(index, val){
        $(".select[id="+val+"] option").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() == value) {
                $(this).hide(); // <----- CHANGE THIS
            }
        });
    });
});
var numbers = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
$.each(numbers, function( key, value ) {
    if (key == 0) {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdownthree").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");

    } else if (key == 1) {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdownthree").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    } else if (key == 2) {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdownthree").append("<option selected='selected' value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
    } else {
        $("#dropdownone").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
        $("#dropdowntwo").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");
       $("#dropdownthree").append("<option value='"+value+"'>"+value+"</option>");    
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to remove the value i just need to hide it.